# Eps file inside postscript file using ghostscript

Tags: pdf, ghostscript, postscript, eps

I am trying to produce production ready pdf.

I have eps file uploaded by admin and postscript file which I generate dynamically. I include eps with in postscript file

using below script

```
%%BeginDocument: danske.eps
(".$bgeps_path.") run
%%EndDocument
```

Now my problem is, there should be 10 mm space around image.

I managed to add 10mm space into pdf via translate.

But when It goes to print, printer cuts two edges, one is with 10mm space and other with image edge.

So what I want is to allow only one edge to cut that is with 10mm space.

I tried to achieve this by playing with BoundingBox but that does help me.

Answer (score 1):

BoundingBox is a comment, nothing more, and as such is usually ignored. If you want to place an EPS then you need to follow the rules for EPS inclusion. You need to set up the Current Transformation Matrix to correctly scale *and position* the EPS on the canvas at a minimum.

Tech Note 5022 the EPSF sepcification v3.0 has guidelines for importing EPS files on page 13, you really should read this, particularly the co-ordinate system transformation on page 16. The tech note is available here:

http://partners.adobe.com/public/developer/en/ps/5002.EPSF_Spec.pdf

Comment: I have managed to set it at correct co-ordinates, my problem is clipping path. I want to set eps image path + 10mm space around in pdf, Now printer should not be able to detect eps image path only my external clipping path should be consider

Comment: IN other words, I have problem with path. Eps image's path and and +10mm space path, So my question is, how can we delete/ignore eps image path.

Comment: Essentially, you can't. The whole point of the EPS is that its a 'black box', you cannot change what's in it. But I do not see any evidence that the 'clipping path' from the EPS is being used. To be honest, your best bet is to put an example EPS file somewhere public so I and others can look at it.

Comment: reading this again, it looks like you need to set the actual physical page size, and are not doing so. So "<</PageSize [x y]>> setpagedevice" where x and y are the size of the EPS and the white space you want around it. This is *not* a clipping path, its the media size.

Comment: Thank you for looking into this.

Comment: I set page size in command same as you mentioned above. 
see my eps and pdf 
http://dev.ramsign.dk.web15.redhost.dk/1373957980.pdf
http://dev.ramsign.dk.web15.redhost.dk/1349147942_ST210x160.eps

Now my problem is when I open pdf in Adobe Illustrator. And Press ctrl+y There would be additional path which is eps image.

I hope this time, I make my point clear.

printer will cut paper twice as there are two path inside pdf.

Comment: I don't have Adobe Illustrator and have no idea what CTRL-Y does in that application. Your PDF file does indeed have a (pointless) clip path in it, because your original EPS file also has the same clip path. Most of the content is the (simple) image. The remaining path is filled (this does not seem to be part of your EPS file) and forms the number 45. Since any PDF file might reasonably contain any number of paths, limiting it to one does not make sense. I don't really understand your problem, seems like your printer is being a bit simple-minded.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33617/discussion-between-user1600540-and-kens)